# Determining the Size of a Rectangle based on Co-ordinates in Java

Tags: java

I've been struggling with this problem for awhile now and I'm looking for some assistance.

1. Information I Know/am given:

   - A series of co-ordinates similar to the following

     - x=5, y=5
     - x=5, y=6
     - x=9, y=10
     - x=1, y=1
     - x=2, y=1
     - x=1, y=2
     - x=2, y=2
   - Every point in this list is part of a rectangle, that is at least 1x1
   - These lists are `int[]`s, with all the x-coords in one array, and all the y-coords in another
   - The array co-ordinates are matched up (e.g. `xcoords[5]` makes an ordered pair with `ycoords[5]`)
   - The size of the arrays are not consistent (it might be 50 x-coords and 50 y-coords)
   - The co-ordinates can be negative
2. What I need to find

   - The number of rectangles in this list (e.g. this example would be 3)
   - The size of each rectangle (e.g. this example would be r1=2x1, r2=1x1, r3=2x2)
   - The format of the results don't matter

Example:

```
public class Rectangle_Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] xcoords = {5,5,9,1,2,1,2};
        int[] ycoords = {5,6,10,1,1,2,2};

    }

}
```

I have an idea of how to approach the problem...

1. Get the first element of each array and assign it a variable

`int initialX = xcoords[0];`
`int initialY = ycoords[0];`
2. Loop through the arrays, and compare the initial values to each value in the array, and reset if both are different

```
if(initialX != xcoords[currentIndex] && initialY != ycoords[currentIndex] && xcoords[currentIndex] != xCoords[currentIndex+1] && ycoords[currentIndex] != yCoords[currentIndex+1]){
    initialX = xcoords[currentIndex];
    initialY = ycoords[currentIndex];
    numRects++;
}
```

3. However, I can't figure out how to determine the rectangle size from the code above...

Comment: Are the edges of the rectangle always parallel to the x and y axes?

Comment: Can rectangles share edges?

Comment: `The number of rectangles in this list (e.g. this example would be 3)` - do you mean the minimum number of rectangles that contain all these points? There are more than 3 rectangles that contain these points (any two points that have different x coordinates and different y coordinates can form a rectangle).

Comment: @Eran yes, the minimum number

Comment: @LanguidSquid, No, they will not share edges

Comment: @Rakesh yes, no diagonal edges

Comment: @JMorris Also, are these points just the corner vertices of a given rectangle?

Comment: @Rakesh these points include the entire rectangle, so if it was 4x3, there would be 12 points.